# Debug logs are not printed on console after spring boot update from 2.7 to 3.2.3 using lombok

Tags: junit5, lombok, spring-boot-3

I have a test case which uses `@ExtendWith(OutputCaptureExtension.class)` and test case is as below.

```
@Test
void testOneSimpleMethodWhichHaveDebugLogs(CapturedOutput output) {
    ....//// When then and everything is here.
    
    Object param = Mockito.mock(Object.class);
    Object.setExampleMap(map);
    Mockito.when(param.getMap()).thenReturn(map);

    ImplementationOfSomeAbstractClass obj = new ImplementationOfSomeAbstractClass();
    Status result = obj.validation(param);
    assertEquals(StatusEnum.NO_CHANGE, result);

    assertTrue(output.getAll().contains("Some Text"));
}
```

The class which have the logger method is as below.

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public abstract class SomeAbstractClass {
    
    protected Status validation(Object param) {
        Status result = Status.UNKNOWN;
        try {
            param1 = someOtherPrivateMethod();
            result = anotherProtectedMethod(param, param1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Invalid.", e);
        }
        return result;
    }   

    protected Result anotherProtectedMethod(Object param, Object param1) {
        try {
            if (somCondition) {
                 log.error("SomeText");
            }

            if (somCondition) {
                 log.warn("SomeText");
            }

            if (somCondition) {
                 log.info("SomeText");
            }

            if (somCondition) {
                 log.debug("SomeText");
            } else {
                 log.info("SomeText");
                 log.info("SomeText");
            }
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            log.error("SomeText");
        }
    log.error("SomeText");
    return null;
  }
}
```

All other log levels are getting printed on the console but somehow debug logs are not getting printed on console and only this single test case is failing.

Please help.